# rails form logic on submit

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a form that contains a selector. there is an "Add New" option, and when that is selected, a text input is dynamically generated with jquery. Now what i need to do is on submit, check for the presence of the text input, and if it exists, update the table with the information from that and ignore the selector. My question is should I be doing this in the model with form validation? Or is there a more appropriate way?

selector:

```
<%= builder.select(:line_id, ['~ Add New ~'] + Line.all.collect {|p| [p.title, p.id ]}, { :include_blank => 'select line' }, :id => "line_selector")
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#line_selector").on("change", function() {
        if($(this).prop("selectedIndex") == 1) { 
            console.log($("#line_selector").prop("selectedIndex"));
            var new_line_title = prompt('Please enter a line title');
            if(!new_line_title.length) {
                console.log("no entry");
                return;
            };
            console.log(new_line_title);
            $(this).after($(document.createElement("input"))
                .attr("type", "text")
                .attr("id", "text")
                .attr("name", "text")
                .attr("value", new_line_title));
        };
    });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a better method, but i would do it in the model with custom validations, as you mentioned. To me it is the best place to define the behavior of your application.

Answer (score 0):

I would just have an attr_accesor for the text field and have a after_initialize callback in your model to set the line attribute.

Also, this has nothing to do with your question itself, but do you plan to hide the input when selecting other value from the dropdown?  If so, instead of dynamically adding the element, why don't you just toggle() and disable/enable the text field?

Comment: when you select anything other than "Add New" the input doesn't show up. It's dynamically created with javascript when "add New" is selected